# PDF text replace not working properly

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I use to replace the text in a .pdf file using the code given here

```
public void doIt( String inputFile, String outputFile, String strToFind, String message) throws IOException, COSVisitorException
{
    // the document
    PDDocument doc = null;
    try
    {
        doc = PDDocument.load( inputFile );
        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for( int i=0; i<pages.size(); i++ )
        {
            PDPage page = (PDPage)pages.get( i );
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream() );
            parser.parse();
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();
            for( int j=0; j<tokens.size(); j++ )
            {
                Object next = tokens.get( j );
                if( next instanceof PDFOperator )
                {
                    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator)next;
                    //Tj and TJ are the two operators that display
                    //strings in a PDF
                    if( op.getOperation().equals( "Tj" ) )
                    {
                        //Tj takes one operator and that is the string
                        //to display so lets update that operator
                        COSString previous = (COSString)tokens.get( j-1 );
                        String string = previous.getString();
                        if (string.matches(strToFind)) {
                            string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                            previous.reset();
                            previous.append( string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
                        }
                    }
                    else if( op.getOperation().equals( "TJ" ) )
                    {
                        COSArray previous = (COSArray)tokens.get( j-1 );
                        for( int k=0; k<previous.size(); k++ )
                        {
                            Object arrElement = previous.getObject( k );
                            if( arrElement instanceof COSString )
                            {
                                COSString cosString = (COSString)arrElement;
                                String string = cosString.getString();
                                if (string.matches(strToFind)) 
                                {
                                    string = string.replaceFirst( strToFind, message );
                                    cosString.reset();
                                    cosString.append( string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") );
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //now that the tokens are updated we will replace the
            //page content stream.
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
            tokenWriter.writeTokens( tokens );
            page.setContents( updatedStream );
        }
        doc.save( outputFile );
    }
    finally
    {
        if( doc != null )
        {
            doc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This code works for very few formats. for most of the format it reads text like this

```
A
d
obe 
A
c
r
obat PDF Fi
les
Adobe® Portable Do
cument F
o
rm
at (PDF
) is 
a universal 
file 
format
```

Because of this strange reading, the replace functionality is not working. Kindly advice me how can I modify my code to work with all format.

Comment: *how can I modify my code to work with all format.* - you can't, and it even requires a lot of coding to make it work for most common cases. PDF is a format not designed for editing.

Comment: This is part of my assignment. Some how I have to do this. We dont have any way to make this working? Please help me to make this working.

Comment: For generic pdfs your assignment means a lot of work, and even then you won't be able to edit all pdfs.

Comment: Another problem you could have is that the size of the replaced glyphs is different than the size or the original glyphs.

Comment: Thanks!! for your valuable replies @mkl . Could you please suggest me how can I move forward with my assignment work? Or in this scenario what can I do next? Please ...

Comment: Thanks to Tilman also.  Could you please suggest me how can I move forward with my assignment work? Or in this scenario what can I do next? Please ..

Comment: First of all, as long as your assignment is to make that replacement stuff work for all pdfs, ask for a different assignment. If on the other hand the assignment is limited to certain types of PDF, describe them here. Maybe the limitation makes your task reasonable.

Comment: Thanks! for your valuable suggestions mkl. The code stuff posted here by myself works for only very few basic formats.